# Adding dynamic references to VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I have a piece of code I am using to filter a table of data and copy the visible cells to a new sheet.

```
Sub AddFilter()
'
' AddFilter Macro
'

Dim rCrit1 As Range, rCrit2 As Range, rCrit3 As Range
Dim copyRange1 As Range, copyRange2 As Range, copyRange3 As Range
Dim filterRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

Set src = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined")
Set tgt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")

lastRow = src.Range("A" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set filterRange = src.Range("A1:Z" & lastRow)
Set copyRange1 = src.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
Set copyRange2 = src.Range("G2:G" & lastRow)
Set copyRange3 = src.Range("O2:O" & lastRow)

With Application
.EnableEvents = False
.ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set rCrit1 = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("Ref_1")
Set rCrit2 = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("Ref_2")


Sheets("Dashboard").Range("A1:C3").ClearContents
Sheets("Dashboard").Range("A1:C3").ClearFormats

Selection.AutoFilter
filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=rCrit1, Criteria1:="<>X"
filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=rCrit2, Criteria1:=Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("Ref_3").Value

copyRange1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt.Range("A5")
copyRange2.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt.Range("B5")
copyRange3.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt.Range("C5")

End Sub
```

It works fine as it is but I am having to manually update sections of it when the data I want to copy changes.  The three rCrit values come from a set of 4 cell `D2:G2` on the Dashboard sheet.  `D2` is a data validation drop down list. The values `E2` and `F2` are driven by the drop down selection.  These cells are the named ranges Ref_1 and Ref_2.  G2 is another drop down which can be either YES or NO, this cell is named range Ref_3.

To automate this piece of code I need copyRange3 to dynamically update to use Ref_1 as the column count (i.e. if Ref_1 is 15, the copyRange selects column O).

I also need to have the second autofilter criteria to be the value of Ref_3 (either YES or NO).-Fixed as per comment below

Comment: I have managed to solve the second part of the problem by replacing
`filterRange.Autofilter Field:rCrit2, Criteria1:="YES"` with
`filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=rCrit2, Criteria1:=Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("Ref_3").Value` removing the need for the rCrit3 to be defined earlier in the code

Comment: please [edit] your post to update your code, including only - and exactly - what's required for others to reproduce the problem.  See "[Ask]" as well as *how to create a [mcve]** for your question.  More important tips at the [help/on-topic]

Comment: @ashleedawg posting isolate lines of code with little to no context is of limited benefit to anyone trying to help solve this issue

Comment: You claim to have solved half the issue, it would be respectful of others' time to make that ear up front, and to clarify the focus on what's remaining as a problem. I, for one, could not understand your description..  but suit yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is now solved, by using the code as shown below the sub will dynamically update as required.  By using a combination of offset and the dynamic value for the column that changes, the copy range will dynamically updated.  As pointed out earlier changing the filterRange line of code allows for dynamic criteria

```
Sub AddFilter()
'
' AddFilter Macro
'

Dim rCrit1 As Range, rCrit2 As Range, rCrit3 As Range
Dim copyRange1 As Range, copyRange2 As Range, copyRange3 As Range
Dim filterRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

Set src = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined")
Set tgt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")

Set rCrit1 = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("Ref_1")
Set rCrit2 = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("Ref_2")

lastRow = src.Range("A" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set filterRange = src.Range("A1:Z" & lastRow)
Set copyRange1 = src.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
Set copyRange2 = src.Range("C2:C" & lastRow)
Set copyRange3 = src.Range("D2:D" & lastRow)
Set copyRange4 = src.Range("G2:G" & lastRow)
Set copyRange5 = src.Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Offset(0, rCrit1 - 1)

With Application
.EnableEvents = False
.ScreenUpdating = False
End With


Sheets("Dashboard").Range("A5:E" & lastRow).ClearContents
Sheets("Dashboard").Range("A5:E" & lastRow).ClearFormats

Selection.AutoFilter
filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=rCrit1, Criteria1:="<>X"
filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=rCrit2, Criteria1:=Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("Ref_3").Value

copyRange1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt.Range("A5")
copyRange2.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt.Range("B5")
copyRange3.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt.Range("C5")
copyRange4.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt.Range("D5")
copyRange5.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt.Range("E5")

Sheets("Dashboard").Range("A5:E" & lastRow).ClearFormats

End Sub
```